# Why doesn't this transaction rollback?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

When I execute this script, the first `INSERT` works even though the second `INSERT` fails due to a NOT NULL constraint on Fluffiness. Why does the first row persist and why isn't it rolled back?

```
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO tCat(Cat, Fluffiness) VALUES('Sir Pounce A Lot', 8.0)
    INSERT INTO tCat(Cat)             VALUES('Violet')
COMMIT
```

Here is the table script

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tCat]
(
    [CatID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Cat] [NCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [CatBreedID] [INT] NULL,
    [Fluffiness] [FLOAT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tCat] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([CatID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON`:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO tCat(Cat, Fluffiness) VALUES('Sir Pounce A Lot', 8.0)
    INSERT INTO tCat(Cat)             VALUES('Violet')
COMMIT
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1810c0103312a6562bb480cb0421364)**

Related article: [Error Handling in SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html)

> This table lists some common errors, and whether they **abort the current statement or the entire batch.**
>
> ```
> +---------------------+-----------+
> |        Error        |  Aborts   |
> +---------------------+-----------+
> | NOT NULL violation. | Statement |
> +---------------------+-----------+
> ```
>
> What I have said this far applies to when XACT_ABORT is OFF, which is the default. **When you issue SET XACT_ABORT ON, the very most of the statement-terminating errors instead become batch-aborting errors**